# multiple webRTC replaceTrack() calls for swapping two video streams

Tags: ios, flutter, webrtc, flutter-webrtc

I'm making a video call application with two video sources: camera / screen record,
and let the users switch camera <-> screen record multiple times during a call.
RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack() allows me to replace the camera stream with the screen record stream.

But if I try to switch back to the camera stream, it doesn't work on ios.
On android, I found [this document](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/RtpSender.java). It seems that replaceTrack() will auto-dispose the track when it's no longer needed. If I use setTrack(_, takeOwnership=false), and it works ok.

I wonder if I can do the same on ios.

I'm developing a flutter application & using [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc), but I wonder if this is even possible on ios native.